# MongoDb - geospatial join

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

### Option 1: solve the query

I'm trying to perform a complex join between two collections, using coordinates as the join match, and I receive the following error message:

> Error: command failed: {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$geoWithin'",
>       "code" : 168,
>       "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
>   }

This is what my query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('grdFile').aggregate([
                {"$match": {"stack_id":"TSX010_A"}},
                {"$lookup":
                    {
                        "from": "stand",
                        "let": {"image_geometry": "$geometry",
                                "acquisition_date": "$acquisition_date"},
                        "pipeline": [
                            {"$match":
                                {"$expr":
                                    {"$and":
                                        [

                                            {"bounding_box": {
                                                "$geoWithin": {
                                                    "$geometry": {
                                                        "type": "Polygon",
                                                        "coordinates": "$$image_geometry"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }

                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "as": "stands"

                    }

                }
                ]
                )
```

If I replace `"bounding_box"` with `"$bounding_box"` it complains instead that it doesn't recognize the expression `"$bounding_box"`.

**Edit**:
I'm using `$expr` in order to access variables from the `let` clause.  Without `$expr` I can use `$geoWithin` but can't access the variables.

My question is this: is there some other operator I can use to make this work, or is there a limitation in Mongo that doesn't allow use of geo operators in the `$expr` clause at all?

### Option 2: am I trying to solve this problem the right way?

The problem is as follows: I have a collection that represents geoTIFF files, with the coordinates of the boundary of the footprint, and a collection of polygons with metadata associated with them.  I want to query the images collection (with or without filters) and join to each record those polygons that fall within the image boundary (with or without additional filters on the polygons' metadata).  I thought I could achieve this using the `$lookup` aggregation, but the limitations I ran into (see above) have made me look for other possibilities.  The one idea I came up with is make a lookup table myself, i.e. a collection I'll call `imagePolygonLookup` that contains two fields - `polygon_id` and `image_id`.  It's a classic many-to-many lookup table.  Then I'll be able to use that collection as a base for `$lookup` queries on either (or both) of the other collections.

Is this some other, third way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to use `$expr`. I don't think there is need of `$expr` here. It is creating conflict here as we can only use aggregation operator inside the `$expr` and the `$geoWithin` is an query operator.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I edited the question.  Please have a look

Comment: Have a look at comments of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624316/in-mongodb-how-do-i-perform-a-geowithin-query-as-part-of-an-aggregation-pipeli#comment110747013_62624316