# In MongoDB, how do I perform a $geoWithin query as part of an aggregation pipeline that utilizes $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use an aggregation pipeline to determine whether a specific `territory` has specific territories that match `$geoWithin`. Each `territory` has a geojson `geometry` object that is indexed appropriately. I'm not sure I am using `let` properly in this pipeline or if there is a way to coerce MongoDB into recognizing the parameters as appropriate `geojson`. I get the following error with the pipeline below:

`unknown GeoJSON type: { type: "$$type", coordinates: "$$coords" }`

```js
const findTerritoriesWithin = (_id: string) => [
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': new ObjectId(_id)
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'territories', 
      'let': {
        'type': '$geometry.type', 
        'coords': '$geometry.coordinates'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            'geometry': {
              '$geoWithin': {
                '$geometry': {
                  'type': '$$type', 
                  'coordinates': '$$coords'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'matchingTerritories'
    }
  }
];
const collection = db.collection('territories');
const results = await collection.aggregate(findTerritoriesWithin('5ef2408033a243ced1f02d1e'))
```

I also tried

```js
{
  from: 'territories',
  let: { 
    geometry: '$geometry'
  },
  pipeline: [
    { 
      $match: {
        'geometry': {
          $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: '$$geometry'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'matching_territories'
}
```

but that yields: `unknown geo specifier: $geometry: "$$geometry"`

MongoDB version: `4.2.2.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works at all, this is going to be painfully slow because a spatial index will not be used. Reword your query to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/ as the first pipeline stage.

Comment: @D.SM ah, is the spatial index not going to be used because the query is within a `$lookup` pipeline? 

This is going to be a heavily used query. I was hoping to shave time off each hit by not having to make several round trips carrying the poly/multipoly payload. They can be rather large. 

I guess I'll roll with that for now.

Comment: Performance aside, sadly this can't be done. the geospatial queries are "unique" hence they are parsed differently which makes them unable to receive parameters like so,

Comment: I created a territoryWithin collection. It'll be faster this way anyway. Thanks @TomSlabbaert

Comment: @Chance Have you figured this out ?