# Getting error called Point must be an array or object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    $match:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        "mapboxAddress.complete":
          "Felix-Wankel-Straße 15, 74172 Neckarsulm, Germany",
      },
  },
  {
    $lookup:
      /**
       * from: The target collection.
       * localField: The local join field.
       * foreignField: The target join field.
       * as: The name for the results.
       * pipeline: Optional pipeline to run on the foreign collection.
       * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
       */
      {
        from: "pg-boundaries-prod",
        // Adjust this to match the actual collection name
        let: {
          coordinates:
            "$mapboxAddress.geometry.coordinates",
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              geometry: {
                $geoIntersects: {
                  $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: "$$coordinates",
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "boundariesData",
      },
  },
]
```

Here is the pipeline which I am trying to execute and I am getting error called **Point must be an array or object** and here is the my mapboxAdress object

```
{
    "number": "15",
    "locality": "",
    "postcode": "74172",
    "city": "Neckarsulm",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        9.224392,
        49.193724
      ]
    },
    "address": "felix-wankel-straße 15",
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Baden-Württemberg",
    "complete": "Felix-Wankel-Straße 15, 74172 Neckarsulm, Germany",
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6512e2eb0524fcb6bcdc9bd3"
    }
  }
```

Also If try to run the pipeline with static values on lookup function then it is working fine but why it's not working when I try to do this dynamic

Also please note I have already tried other things like using $toDouble for each coordinate but it was not working...

Please help me to identify and solve this problem, thank you for your time.

Error image
[image: Error image]
for which table we are doing our lookup
[image: for which table we are doing our lookup]
It just work fine when I direct add the lat and long
[image: It just work fine when I direct add the lat and long]

here is the sample document for quote collection

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "mapboxAddress": {
    "number": "15",
    "locality": "",
    "postcode": "74172",
    "city": "Neckarsulm",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        9.224392,
        49.193724
      ]
    },
    "address": "felix-wankel-straße 15",
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Baden-Württemberg",
    "complete": "Felix-Wankel-Straße 15, 74172 Neckarsulm, Germany",
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6512e2eb0524fcb6bcdc9bd3"
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "green": {
      "imgUrl": [],
      "editedCanvas": [],
      "moduleQuantity": 71,
      "consumption": 28222.5,
      "totalCost": 37378.7095,
      "roofTilt": "45°",
      "roofType": "Arched roof",
      "roofMaterial": "metal roof",
      "roofStatusRating": 1,
      "roofOrientation": "South orientation",
      "shadowsRating": 1,
      "projectType": "R",
      "roofMaterialRating": 2,
      "rating": 4,
      "grn": "07vcGa6FR2xTIbJLMzGAJhEa",
      "productionRatio": 830,
      "totalCostFromProvider": 34612,
      "projectSizeRating": 3,
      "annualSolarGeneration": 19144,
      "currentAnnualConsumption": 4500,
      "annulElectricBill": 1699.44,
      "roofStructureComplexityRating": 3,
      "isVerified": "not verified",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6512e2eb0524fcb6bcdc9bd4"
      },
      "ModelNo": "Neckarsulm_96_X_G",
      "calculations": {
        "profit": 30196,
        "feedInSavingsTillNow": 40925,
        "electricityBillSavingsTillNow": 26650,
        "investmentAndCost": 37378.7095,
        "gains": 67575,
        "evGridCostTillNow": 0,
        "appliedProjectCost": 37378.7095,
        "amortizationTime": 16,
        "production": 23424.675,
        "systemCapacity": 28222.5
      }
    },
    "eco": {
      "imgUrl": [],
      "editedCanvas": [],
      "moduleQuantity": 71,
      "consumption": 28222.5,
      "totalCost": 37378.7095,
      "roofTilt": "45°",
      "roofType": "Arched roof",
      "roofMaterial": "metal roof",
      "roofStatusRating": 1,
      "roofOrientation": "South orientation",
      "shadowsRating": 1,
      "projectType": "R",
      "roofMaterialRating": 2,
      "rating": 4,
      "grn": "07vcGa6FR2xTIbJLMzGAJhEa",
      "productionRatio": 830,
      "totalCostFromProvider": 34612,
      "projectSizeRating": 3,
      "annualSolarGeneration": 19144,
      "currentAnnualConsumption": 4500,
      "annulElectricBill": 1699.44,
      "roofStructureComplexityRating": 3,
      "isVerified": "not verified",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6512e2eb0524fcb6bcdc9bd5"
      },
      "ModelNo": "Neckarsulm_96_X_E",
      "calculations": {
        "profit": 30196,
        "feedInSavingsTillNow": 40925,
        "electricityBillSavingsTillNow": 26650,
        "investmentAndCost": 37378.7095,
        "gains": 67575,
        "evGridCostTillNow": 0,
        "appliedProjectCost": 37378.7095,
        "amortizationTime": 16,
        "production": 23424.675,
        "systemCapacity": 28222.5
      }
    },
    "smart": {
      "imgUrl": [],
      "editedCanvas": [],
      "moduleQuantity": 71,
      "consumption": 28222.5,
      "totalCost": 37378.7095,
      "roofTilt": "45°",
      "roofType": "Arched roof",
      "roofMaterial": "metal roof",
      "roofStatusRating": 1,
      "roofOrientation": "South orientation",
      "shadowsRating": 1,
      "projectType": "R",
      "roofMaterialRating": 2,
      "rating": 4,
      "grn": "07vcGa6FR2xTIbJLMzGAJhEa",
      "productionRatio": 830,
      "totalCostFromProvider": 34612,
      "projectSizeRating": 3,
      "annualSolarGeneration": 19144,
      "currentAnnualConsumption": 4500,
      "annulElectricBill": 1699.44,
      "roofStructureComplexityRating": 3,
      "isVerified": "not verified",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6512e2eb0524fcb6bcdc9bd6"
      },
      "ModelNo": "Neckarsulm_96_X_S",
      "calculations": {
        "profit": 30196,
        "feedInSavingsTillNow": 40925,
        "electricityBillSavingsTillNow": 26650,
        "investmentAndCost": 37378.7095,
        "gains": 67575,
        "evGridCostTillNow": 0,
        "appliedProjectCost": 37378.7095,
        "amortizationTime": 16,
        "production": 23424.675,
        "systemCapacity": 28222.5
      }
    }
  },
  "installerPartner": "",
  "roofOrientation": "South orientation",
  "roofTilt": "45°",
  "roofType": "Arched roof",
  "roofMaterial": "metal roof",
  "projectType": "R",
  "shadowsRating": 1,
  "roofOrientationRating": 4,
  "roofStatusRating": 1,
  "buildingType": "Single-Family Building",
  "geohash": "u0t8vnttm7",
  "long": "9.224392",
  "roofTypesList": [],
  "lat": "49.193724",
  "status": "PRIORITY_PLANNING",
  "isActive": true,
  "ganeratedFromPartner": true,
  "batchName": "Hubspot ganerated",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2022-11-30T11:42:21.000Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-23T13:34:58.808Z"
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "6461e3fb66aa0c40a3770313"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "projectStatus": "Not accessed",
  "Gemeindeschluessel8": "08125065",
  "pvInstalled": "no solar deployed",
  "houseInfo": {
    "bbox": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            9.22432,
            49.19368
          ],
          [
            9.22432,
            49.19377
          ],
          [
            9.22446,
            49.19377
          ],
          [
            9.22446,
            49.19368
          ],
          [
            9.22432,
            49.19368
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

here is the sample document for pg-boundaries-prod

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "657745577c956d0a86ea650d"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gid": 10476,
    "adresse": "keine Postanschrift",
    "status": "Bestand",
    "funktion": "Schu",
    "dachneig": null,
    "flur_id": "720_4373_0",
    "dachform": null,
    "unterirdis": 0,
    "Stadtteil": "Neckarsulm",
    "geb_hoehe": 4.28
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          9.2471761670631,
          49.18832464401746
        ],
        [
          9.247283271304585,
          49.18837323893382
        ],
        [
          9.24740273956032,
          49.188260669642794
        ],
        [
          9.247295222837854,
          49.18821189549828
        ],
        [
          9.2471761670631,
          49.18832464401746
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Found the answer this query works fine

```
[
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [9.225169, 49.193546]
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      maxDistance: 1000 * 1000,
      spherical: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "mapboxAddress.complete": "Felix-Wankel-Straße 15, 74172 Neckarsulm, Germany"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      distanceInKm: { $divide: ["$distance", 1000] },
      modifiedMapboxAddress: { $concat: ["$mapboxAddress.complete", ", Germany"] }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { distance: 1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "pg-boundaries-prod",
      let: { coordinates: "$mapboxAddress.geometry.coordinates" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: "$$coordinates"},
            distanceField: "distance",
            spherical: true
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "boundariesData"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      distanceInKm: 1,
      boundariesData: { $arrayElemAt: ["$boundariesData", 0] }, // Selecting only the first element
      _id: 1,
      mapboxAddress: 1,
      corr: "$mapboxAddress.geometry.coordinates",
      houseInfo: 1
    }
  },
  { $limit: 1 } // Optionally limit the result to just one document
]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample document for quotes collection?

Comment: yes sure let me put that into my question

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is not possible to work the geospatial query like `$geoIntersects` in the `$lookup` stage especially requiring the `$expr` to get the variable value. Possibly relate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62624316/8017690

Comment: I found the solution with $geonear added on question 
thank you

Comment: Glad to see you found out the answer. While, please write the answer as an answer post instead of writing in the question. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.)